# How to use circular mode in stm32f429zi?

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I am working on the DMA Peripheral , and i have some confusion about the circular mode`s parameters . i have tried to sort it out on my own . so i put an example and i want someone to tell me if i correctly understood it or i need someone to explain it for me 
Assume that I want to keep transferring 128 Half-word from a peripheral to a memory .
assume:-

```
PSIZE=Half-Word(2bytes)
MSIZE=WORD(4bytes) 
PBURST=16
```

so according to the PSIZE being a half-word that means the beat is a half-word so in each burts i am going to transfer 16beats which are 16half-words correct?
according to the reference manual it is noted that

```
NDTR=multipleof(PBURST * (MSIZE/PSIZE))
```

so in my example the NDTR is multiple of (32) correct?
up till now if i am correct , what is the value that should be written in the NDTR according to these configurations?and if i am wrong please guide me to the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation is self explanatory: 
[image]